# Syncfusion Report Designer Customization

Tags: jquery, asp.net, syncfusion, report-designer

How do we get the RDL content From SyncFusion Report designer? 
How can we load Syncfusion resport designer by RDL content (No external files just RDL xml is there).

`var designer = $('#ReportDesigner1').data('ejReportDesigner'); //How will I get RDL content from this?
designer.openReport('/Catagory2/Tickets Sales Analysis'); // Instead of physical file how do i pass RDL content and load design..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the sample below to save or open the report from RDL XML Content using External server in web Report Designer,

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ReportDesignerSample-193940820.zip

**Note**: In above sample we have used the External server for open/edit/save the existing report RDL XML Content to DB using External server.

Please use the Open from Server and Save As -> To Server options in above sample to open and save to DB.

**Sample Details:**

1. You can find the Sample Database below which we used to store the RDL XML content in DB using above sample,
   http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ExternalServer-1188543789.zip
2. ExternalServer Class file in above sample contains the code to open/save the RDL report content to DB.
3. SQLDataHelper Class file in above sample contains the code to establish connection with SQL Server to access the ExternalServer database which has been shared.